# How to zoom in the content of cell in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

In the above image,A,B,C,D,E are each custom cell,of collection view and i want to zoom in the cell one by one like c cell.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you should have one more kind of customized cell for zoomed effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just call this method when your collectionviewcell click**

```
[self animateZoomforCell:cell]; // pass cell as collectionviewcell

-(void)animateZoomforCell:(UICollectionViewCell*)zoomCell
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.6,1.6);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
}
-(void)animateZoomforCellremove:(UICollectionViewCell*)zoomCell
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
}
```

Comment: @ParveshSingh is there your problem solve then approve my answer and give vote so other user can also find a solution. thank you. happy coding

Comment: @ParveshSingh you can also use this method for zoom tableviewcell also you just change one thing that UICollectionViewCell to UITableviewCell

Answer (score 1):

In **swift 3** based on Himanshu Moradiya solution:

```
 func animateZoomforCell(zoomCell : UICollectionViewCell)
{
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.2,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
        animations: {
                        zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            },
    completion: nil)
}
func animateZoomforCellremove(zoomCell : UICollectionViewCell)
{
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.2,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
        animations: {
            zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    },
        completion: nil)

}
```